# nginx: Looking to serve multiple subdirectories as their own root

Tags: nginx, server, document-root, nginx-location

## Using Nginx, is there was way to run multiple subdirectories as their own self contained roots (document root)?

I am going to have several (40+) projects run in subdirectories:

- frontend.example.com/project_1
- frontend.example.com/project_2
- frontend.example.com/project_3

Each projects are pushed to their own location `/var/www/html/project_name`. There will not be a site at `frontend.example.com`

Some projects due to the way they are set up need to run as if they are the root. They contain sources like `<img src="/images">`. The page is looking at `front.example.com/images` and not `front.example.com/project_a/images`.

Can I run each of these projects with the subdirectories as the root folder; stopping at `front.example.com/project_name/`?

#### What I've tried that hasn't worked

Creating separate sites-available / sites-enabled and config files. This was tedious since i would need to do this for every site and I kept running into issues. I halted this path to save myself from a rabbit hole, but I can provide those config files, if this is the preferred direction.

#### What has worked so far...

In `sites-available/default` having aliases. So having `location /images/` look at `alias /var/www/html/project_a/images/`. This works, but I am hard coding the project_a, and with potentially a lot of separate project, this is not ideal.

Comment: You have a predefined list of domains? if yes, you don't want to write those subdomains mannually, right?

Comment: Right, I would prefer it agnostic the the subdirectory name

Comment: So, resumming, you want a script that dinamically catch every subdomain and automagically send the traffic to /var/www/html/domain_name? if you want this, check http://serverfault.com/a/459471

Comment: `<img src="/images">` is a show stopper. Each application will expect its resources to be served from the root. Either fix your applications or use multiple subdomains.